# PhpStorm + XDebug + Symfony not working

Tags: phpstorm, symfony, xdebug

I am beginner with XDebug, even with PhpStorm and Symfony in general.
I am trying to run XDebug now, but I am not able to get it triggered from PhpStorm.

I have come through some basic setting pages, like [this one](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm)

You can check some of my local settings:

[image: phpinfo]

[image: url]

[image: phpini]

[image: breakpoint]

[image: listening]

[image: chrome]

[image]

NGinx

[image: nginx]

etc/hosts

[image: hosts]

Comment: Have you set xdebug cookie? I can be done with bookmarklets: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

Comment: I am not using exactly these bookmarklets. But I have posted pictures with 3 Chrome extensions installed, toggled on and IDE is correctly set to PHPSTORM. I can try this exact bookmarklet, if this makes any difference.

Comment: Have you set xdebug port 9000?

Comment: Where is located blackbox.dev? Isn't it a virtual machine or docker container?

Comment: I have updated pictures with info from etc/hosts and nginx conf file.

Comment: I would check with bookmarklet in first place to make sure it's not an issue with your chrome extensions.

Comment: What OS you are on -- Windows?

Comment: 1) Upgrade your xdebug -- 2.5.0**RC1** has issues on Windows -- **use 2.5.0 final** 2) Since you are using nginx .. it's better if you use 9001 (or another) port for xdebug communications (change it both in php.ini and PhpStorm settings) -- nginx communicates with php-fpm using TCP 9000 by default (at least on Linux/Mac) .. so xdebug may be connecting to php-fpm instead of PhpStorm. 3) `xdebug.remote_host` -- better have it as `127.0.0.1` instead of domain name (which may get deleted at some point in the future) - it has to be an address where PhpStorm is running and not site name.

Comment: LazyOne, thank you very much! It seems like 2.5 final solved the problem. Somehow 9001 doesn't work, but 9000 does. I now have to study, how to map filepath correctly, because debugger won't let me continue because of the "Force break at the first line when no path mapping specified" setting. I don't understand how this mapping works. Thank you very much once more.

Comment: So, I have another problem. XDebug is being triggered at PHPStorm, but I get message "Debug session was finished without being paused - 
It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects." I don't know how to correc it. I have tried fiddling with path mappings, but no result so far.

Comment: It works! The problem was with xdebug.remote_mode = jit. After deleting this line it works.

Comment: @Neon You may post your solution (all steps you took) as an answer -- will help others in similar situation. You may then later even accept your own answer (gives more visibility -- a problem/question with found solution -- good indicator when searching)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LazyOne I have found the solution.
His advice was right: "Upgrade your xdebug -- 2.5.0RC1 has issues on Windows -- use 2.5.0 final"

Even after upgrading xdebug, I was still having problems, but that was caused by some leftover settings that I tried in an effort to get it working.

Especially this setting "xdebug.remote_mode = jit" was stopping me from having Xdebug stop at my predefined breakpoint. After removing it, it was easy and I can now see, that tutorials are really right.

I shouldn't use RC releases next time, to save hassles.